# Error 403 during POST on SharePoint 2013 REST API [on premise]

Tags: c#, rest, sharepoint-2013, dotnet-httpclient

I am struggling to understand why am I getting Error 403 while creating a list item using httpclient. I have full control on the list and yet I receive 403 and its very frustrating. I have gone through so many solution but none of them worked for me.

If I create HTML page with ajax calls to the list , I am able to create list items from the browser but the same code written in c# throws error 403.

Here is my C# test code which throws 403 with response as

```
{"error":{"code":"-2130575251, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again."}}}
```

---

```
            NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = cred })
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(URL)
            };
            string cmd = "_api/contextinfo";

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json");

            StringContent httpContent = new StringContent("");

            var clientresponse = await client.PostAsync(cmd, httpContent);

            if (clientresponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string formdigest = await clientresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                JToken t = JToken.Parse(formdigest);
                string digest = t["d"]["GetContextWebInformation"]["FormDigestValue"].ToString();
                string[] digestArray = digest.Split(',');

                NetworkCredential cred2 = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = cred2 })
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri(URL)
                };
                client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
                client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json");
                client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "POST");
                client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-RequestDigest", digestArray[0].ToString());


                string path = SendShipments.ListPath + "_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle("Test")/items";

                string content_Post = "{__metadata:{'type':'SP.Data.TestListItem'},Title:'Test'}";


                var httpContent_Post = new StringContent(content_Post, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var clientresponse2 = await client2.PostAsync(path, httpContent_Post);
```

Here is my ajax code which works as expected

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        data: "{__metadata:{'type':'SP.Data.TestListItem'},Title:'Test'}",
        /*where Title is column name and you can add more columns by splitting with ,*/
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.d.results);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
</script>
```

I tried adding `HttpContext.Current.Items["FormDigestValidated"] = true;` but didn't work.

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: To get the sharepoint api working I had to register the app in the tenant with Application permissions (not delegated, which is ui) and upload an X509 certificate for the app. I then need to use the private key associated with the public key in the certificate to sign a JWT in order to get an access token.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `403` error occurs due to invalid `FormDigest` value.
According to those lines:

```
string digest = t["d"]["GetContextWebInformation"]["FormDigestValue"].ToString();
string[] digestArray = digest.Split(',');
```

and

```
client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-RequestDigest", digestArray[0].ToString());
```

digest value is passed without *timestamp part*, which makes form digest value *invalid*, the whole `FormDigestValue` property needs to be passed as a `X-RequestDigest` header instead as demonstrated below:

```
var formDigest = GetFormDigest(client);

var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "_api/web/webs/add");
message.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
message.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", formDigest);
```

where

```
public static string GetFormDigest(HttpClient client)
{
   var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "_api/contextinfo");
   message.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
   var result = client.SendAsync(message).Result;
   result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
   var content = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
   var json = JToken.Parse(content);
   var formDigest = json["d"]["GetContextWebInformation"]["FormDigestValue"].ToString();
   return formDigest;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim for the explanation but unfortunately after trying solution I got the same error.I am able to perform get with no issues but post seems to be related to something at permission level.

Comment: Indeed it might be related with permissions, verified the provided code on my side, seems to be working as expected